# Implement a table structure in Blackberry application

Tags: blackberry

I want to implement a table structure which can have multiple rows and columns based on the API response in my blackberry application. Please advise me on this or send me links to the respectice docs if any.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to the below Link and download zip file:

[TableLayoutManager.java](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Create-a-rich-UI-layout-with-TableLayoutManager/ta-p/445299)

According to that you can send values to that calss.

Comment: Thanks for your response Alishaikh. Can you please let me know how can I add seperators to this columns and rows ?